# How can you make Aegis Augmented Weapon and Crystallize Weapon suit options work with unarmed strikes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

How can you make Aegis Augmented Weapon and Crystallize Weapon suit options work with unarmed strikes?

> **Augmented Weapon**
>
> The astral suit coats the aegis’s weapon. The weapon is treated as if it was one size category larger for damage purposes. The aegis does not suffer any penalties for wielding the weapon. This ability does not stack with effects that increase the aegis’s size category, such as expansion. The aegis must be at least 6th level to select this customization.

and

> **Crystallized Weapon**
>
> The aegis’s astral suit envelopes his melee weapon. The weapon is treated as if made from deep crystal. This treats the weapon as a masterwork weapon if it was not already, and the aegis can pay two power points to charge the weapon with psionic energy which deals 2d6 additional points of damage on its next hit. The weapon stays charged for 1 minute or until it successfully hits, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 2):

### Unarmed strikes are considered *light weapons*.

Unarmed strikes *are not* manufactured weapons, but they are considered light weapons for all purposes. This is explained under [Unarmed Strikes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/strike-unarmed/):

> An unarmed strike is **always considered a light weapon**. Therefore, you can use the Weapon Finesse feat to apply your Dexterity modifier instead of your Strength modifier to attack rolls with an unarmed strike. Unarmed strikes do not count as natural weapons (see Combat). The damage from an unarmed strike is considered weapon damage for the purposes of effects that give you a bonus on weapon damage rolls.

[Weapon Finesse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-finesse-combat-final) says that you require a light weapon to work, as one of the valid targets:

> Benefit: With a light weapon, elven curve blade, rapier, whip, or spiked chain made for a creature of your size category, you may use your Dexterity modifier instead of your Strength modifier on attack rolls.

Which means that unless the rule in question talks only about manufactured weapons, or excludes unarmed strikes or natural weapons, it can be applied to your Unarmed Strikes as well.

This confusion is mostly caused by the spell [Magic Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-weapon/), which states:

> You can’t cast this spell on a natural weapon, such as an **unarmed strike** (instead, see magic fang). **A monk’s unarmed strike is considered a weapon**, and thus it can be enhanced by this spell.

Here it makes a distinction between non-monk's unarmed strikes and monk's unarmed strikes. But this is a specific rule that contradicts a more general rule, and thus the spell cannot be applied to non-monk's unarmed strikes.

However, you would greatly benefit from the customization [Hardened Strikes](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/astral-suits#TOC-Hardened-Strikes), which makes your attacks lethal and avoid attacks of opportunity, on top of freely being able to pick the damage type it deals.